# PHP json data, getting the data but not working

Tags: jquery, json

Any ideas what ive done wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var f_page = "ID";
    var t_page = "ID";

    function add_commas(number) {
        if (number.length > 3) {
            var mod = number.length % 3;
            var output = (mod > 0 ? (number.substring(0,mod)) : '');
            for (i=0 ; i < Math.floor(number.length / 3); i++) {
                if ((mod == 0) && (i == 0)) {
                    output += number.substring(mod+ 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
                } else {
                    output+= ',' + number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
                }
            }
                return (output);
            } else {
                return number;
        }
    }

    // grab from facebook
    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/'+f_page+'?callback=?', function(data) {
        var fb_count = data['likes'].toString();
        fb_count = add_commas(fb_count);
        $('#fb_count').html(fb_count);
    });

    // grab from twitter
    $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='+t_page+'&callback=?', function(data) {
        twit_count = data['followers_count'].toString();
        twit_count = add_commas(twit_count);
        $('#twitter_count').html(twit_count);
    });

    // grab from website
    $.getJSON('json.php?callback=?', function(data) {
        web_count = data['count'].toString();
        web_count = add_commas(web_count);
        $('#website_count').html(web_count);
    });

});
```

but not showing on the html but i do get the response back {"count":3} so maybe data['count'] wrong? the twiiter / facebook ones work but not my count and like i said in console i get back the array

Comment: Please check your Console and show us the exact(!) output of json.php and the add_commas() method

Comment: Sort by key
count 3

and console i get {"count":3}

Comment: ive added more of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was due to the ?callback=? i removed that an d it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse the JSON data

```
$.getJSON('json.php?callback=?', function(data) {
        var responseObj = $.parseJSON(data);
        website_count = responseObj.count;
        website_count = add_commas(website_count);
        $('#website_count').html(website_count);
    });
```

Comment: i use same method for twitter and that works though so should be right in what im doing

Comment: $.parseJSON() will not help as the result of $.getJSON will already be a JSON object. The result of $.parseJSON() on a JSON object will be null.